# Wrong image size aspect ratio when window resized ( only with position relative )

Tags: html, css

The example is very simple, and I'd like to know why these two images behave differently.

The two images have a height of 30%, which means that the two images have to resize when the window height changes. the width of the image must be proportionate at all times because he did not indicate anything.

The difference is that the imagen1 is positioned relatively, and absolute second.

When I run the code and modify the window size, depends on the size, the image1 deforms as shown in the image, while the imagen2 always matiene form correctly. ( A link to the image example below )

¿ Why ?

I need to use relative images not absolutes, and i can´t.

```
    #image1
{
    height:30%;
    position:relative;
}

#image2
{
    height:30%;
    position:absolute;
}

     <img id="image1" src="graficos/personajes/boo_grande.jpg">
     <img id="image2" src="graficos/personajes/boo_grande.jpg">
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dECZa.jpg)

Comment: *Absolute*: This tells the browser that whatever is going to be positioned should be removed from the normal flow of the document and will be placed in an exact location on the page. *Relative*:Relative positioning uses the same four positioning properties as absolute positioning But instead of basing the position of the element upon the browser view port, it starts from where the element would be if it were still in the normal flow.

Comment: If you specify `width:auto;` or `width:auto !important;` for your relative-positioned image, will it fix the problem?

Comment: Sergiy T , no sorry if i put width:auto the problem still here. Just code, so i have to use absolute images if i want keep aspect ratio ? :(